# Getting the key or index of a specific element in a PL/SQL collection?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can we find the key or index for which we know the value? For example, if we know the value in the collection stored is '**Alex**' how can we find it is stored in which index or key?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817149/getting-index-of-element-in-pl-sql-collection

Comment: In PL/SQL, "collection" is a collective name given to three distinct (and quite different) data types: *associative array*, *varray*, and *nested table*. Very likely, the answer to your question will depend on which specific type of "collection" you are talking about. (In fact, strictly speaking, for *nested table* there should be no "index" or "key"; the fact that there is an index is due to the PL/SQL implementation of the concept, and the fact that the user can access the index is a mistake on PL/SQL's part in my opinion.) So, please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index is how you reference specific entries within a collection. But to get the index having the entry value you need to iterate the collection.

```
declare
  type some_collection is  table of integer;
  the_collection some_collection :=
                 some_collection( 4,84,32,97,2,92,3);
  target_value integer := &target_value;
  index_for_some_value integer;
  current_index integer;
begin
   current_index := the_collection.first;  
   while current_index is not null 
     and index_for_some_value is null
   loop
       if the_collection(current_index) = target_value
       then
           index_for_some_value := current_index;
       end if;
       current_index :=the_collection.next(current_index); 
   end loop;

   dbms_output.put_line( 'Target_Value ' || to_char(target_value)
                        || case when index_for_some_value is null
                                then ' not found.'
                                else ' found at index ' || to_char(index_for_some_value) || '.'
                           end
                        );
end;
```

Of course the exact code may depend on both the [collection type](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-collections) and the index type.